# archiving a swift 3 project takes forever

Tags: xcode, build, swift3, archive

I am able to build and run a project converted from swift 2.3 to swift 3 on the device and simulator.  Unfortunately, I can't archive it.  While the project takes 6 minutes to compile and run, it gets stuck in the "Compile Swift Source Files" stage.

I tried the build time analyzer at https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode and simplified a whole bunch of methods which came up on top of the BuildTimeAnalyser's list.

Its been many hours since I started the archive process.   If you have faced this issue, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

I have been having the same issue since converting to Swift 3.0 and found setting the Swift Compiler Optimization Level to None allowed me to archive again. This doesn't resolve the underlying issue, which seems to commonly be due to Swift's type inference, but hopefully you will be able to archive your project again.

[image: Swift Compiler Settings]

Comment: Thanks I tried the same this morning and it solved my problem.  There is definitely a bug in the Swift optimizer that makes it keep churning away.  I ran it for 48 hours and it did not end optimizing, and after turning it off, it worked right off the bat.

Comment: @Navi: if this solved your problem then you should mark it as the answer so taht everyone can see it :)